Problem regarding arranging divs in a row
I'm trying to arrange a set of divs that look like this:
<div class="productionList">
   <div>
       <img>
       <progress>
   </div>
</div>

inside of a larger div (.productionList)
but no matter what i try they each get their own line:
[img]
[progress]
[img]
[progress] 
...
although i want it to look like this: 
[---img--][---img--][---img--][---img--][---img--][---img--]... 
[progress][progress][progress][progress][progress][progress]... 
(wrap once it reaches end of container) 
[---img--][---img--]
[progress][progress]
This is what my css code looks like:
.productionList {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100%;
}

.productionList div {
    width: 40px;
}

.productionList div img {
    width: 100%;
}

.productionList div progress {
    width: 100%;
}


any idea what's going on or how to fix this?
for reproduction
<style>


.productionList {

    border: 1px solid white;

    width: 100%;

}



.productionList div {

    width: 40px;

}



.productionList div img {

    width: 100%;

}



.productionList div progress {

    width: 100%;


}
</style>

<div class="productionList">

   <div>

       <img>

       <progress>

   </div>

   <div>

       <img>

       <progress>

   </div>

   <div>

       <img>

       <progress>

   </div>

</div>


JS code for reproduction:

    let y = "";
    for (let i = 0; i<player.production.length; i++) y = y + `<div id="production${i+1}"><img src="./img/button/production_empty.svg" id="productionButton${i+1}"><progress min="0" max="1" id="production${i+1}Progress"></progress>`;
    document.getElementById('productionList').innerHTML = y;


i think this question need more detail pleas read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example 

You need a display: inline-block; inside your divs that contain the image and the progress:


.productionList {

    border: 1px solid white;

    width: 120px;
    
}


.productionList > div {

    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;

}



.productionList div img {

    width: 100%;

}



.productionList div progress {

    width: 100%;


}
<div class="productionList">

   <div>

       <img>

       <progress>

   </div>

   <div>

       <img>

       <progress>

   </div>

   <div>

       <img>

       <progress>

   </div>

</div>




i needed to add a closing "</div>" in my javascript
  let y = "";
    for (let i = 0; i<player.production.length; i++) y = y + `<div id="production${i+1}"><img src="./img/button/production_empty.svg" id="productionButton${i+1}"><progress min="0" max="1" id="production${i+1}Progress"></progress>`;
    document.getElementById('productionList').innerHTML = y;


That's correct. Don't forget the player object too

the player object exists in a 600-line file lol
